# Can I throw error in axios post based on response status

Tags: javascript, axios

Is it possible to throw an error on purpose inside the .then() block in axios? For instance, if the api responds with 204 status code, could I throw an error and run the catch block?

For example:

```
axios.post('link-to-my-post-service', {
        json-input
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            //proceed...
        }
        else {
            // throw error and go to catch block
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        //run this code always when status!==200
    });
```

**EDIT**

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var instance = axios.create({
            validateStatus: function (status)
            {
                return status == 200;
            }
        });
axios.post('link-to-my-post-service', {input: myInput}, instance)
    .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
                    payload: response.data
                });
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch({
                type: "FETCH_FAILED",
                payload: error
            });
        });
```

When I get a status code 204, still the executed block is then() block instead of the catch block.

**EDIT 2**

The correct answer using Ilario's suggestion is this:

```
var instance = axios.create({
            validateStatus: function (status)
            {
                return status == 200;
            }
        });
instance.post('link-to-my-post-service', {input: myInput})
    .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
                    payload: response.data
                });
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch({
                type: "FETCH_FAILED",
                payload: error
            });
        });
```

Now when the status code is not equal to 200 the catch block code is executed.

Comment: glad it works now !!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you give a look at the GitHub [Project Page](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) you will notice following option description.

```
/* `validateStatus` defines whether to resolve or reject the promise for a given
 * HTTP response status code. If `validateStatus` returns `true` (or is set to `null`
 * or `undefined`), the promise will be resolved; otherwise, the promise will be
 */ rejected.
validateStatus: function (status) {

    return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default
},
```

So you could create an Instance with your own configuration.

```
var instance = axios.create({

   validateStatus: function (status) {

        return status == 200;
    },
});
```

You could also set defaults. These will be applied to every request.

```
axios.defaults.validateStatus = () => {

    return status == 200;
};
```

**UPDATE 1**

To set the config only on a specific operation you could replace "config" with your desired values or methods.

```
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

**UPDATE 2**

> I tried this, but it didn't work.

You cannot pass the instance to axios.post(). You must call post on the new instance.

```
var instance = axios.create({

    validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status == 200;
    }
});

instance.post('url', data, config);
```

Answer (score 15):

Thank you very much for your suggestions. The answer was simpler than I expected.

I didn't want to set any default options to change the behavior of axios, so I just tried something like the code below, and it worked. Every time the code `throw new Error("Error");` is executed, the catch block code is executed after that.

```
axios.post('link-to-my-post-service', {
        json-input
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            //proceed...
        }
        else {
            // throw error and go to catch block
            throw new Error("Error");
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        //when throw "Error" is executed it runs the catch block code
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Why you do not wanna set default options? Or create an instance with these options set? Do you need it only with a specific request? Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback! I need it only for a specific request

Comment: Okaay. So if you need it only for a specific request, you can do it as you've proposed or take a look at "Update 1" in my answer.

Comment: `if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {` is safer